# Webassembly throwing - memory access out of bounds

Tags: go, memory-management, webassembly

I have followed the tutorial on blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/go-wasm for generating the .wasm file from golang language.

I faced the below error when I execute the program,

> */home/user/test >* node wasm_exec.js test.wasm

```
RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
    at memchr (wasm-function[75]:96)
    at internal_bytealg.IndexByteString (wasm-function[72]:24)
    at runtime.findnull (wasm-function[683]:227)
    at runtime.gostring (wasm-function[678]:126)
    at runtime.goenvs_unix (wasm-function[604]:639)
    at runtime.goenvs (wasm-function[432]:86)
    at runtime.schedinit (wasm-function[498]:780)
    at runtime.rt0_go (wasm-function[860]:165)
    at _rt0_wasm_js (wasm-function[907]:71)
    at global.Go.run (/home/user/test/wasm_exec.js:378:24)
```

Sometimes getting the below error too,

> runtime: memory allocated by OS [0x30000000, 0x938ab2fd34000000) not
>   in usable address space: end outside usable address space
>
> fatal error:
>   memory reservation exceeds address space limit

I have used the default WebAssembly.Memory of this program (default memory is around 1033MB).

```
    WebAssembly.instantiate(fs.readFileSync("test.wasm"), go.importObject).then((result) => {
process.on("exit", () => { // Node.js exits if no callback is pending
                    if (!go.exited) {
                        console.error("error: all goroutines asleep and no JavaScript callback pending - deadlock!");
                        process.exit(1);
                    }
                });
                result.instance.exports.run()
                return go.run(result.instance);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
                go.exited = true;
                process.exit(1);
            });
```

Is anything I missed here?

Comment: You can run this example: https://github.com/udhos/hellowasm/ (you will need you have Go 1.11beta1).

Comment: What is the difference between those two examples? I explore this package and didn't find anything from the previous example? Can you please explain this?

Comment: The tutorial you have tried is from before wasm landing as supported Go platform. If you install go1.11beta1 or higher, you can more easily run the example I pointed out. Or other examples on the Internet, like this: https://sebastian-holstein.de/post/2018-07-05-go-wasm-application/